# Adding VB.net DLL's to MS Word VBA Macro

Tags: vb.net, vba, dll, ms-word

i have tried adding a reference to a DLL from a Macro project in ms word. the dll has been build using MS Visual web Express 2010 with this official MS Knowledgebase article

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317535

but im getting this error when trying to add it to my macro as a reference:
[error http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/5859/13082012111759.png](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/5859/13082012111759.png)

As said, i followed all steps in the knowledgebase article.

What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Your component/class needs to be com-visible!

Try to specify the [ComVisibleAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx).
Then it must be [registered with your system](http://www.ewall.org/tech/msi/com-registration).